# how to get the i-th underlying type (by an const integer) of af boost::variant

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, boost-variant

I would like to get the underlying type of a variant. For example"something similar to this:

```
typedef boost::variant< shared_ptr<int> , shared_ptr<float> > VType;

typedef VType::get<0>::type  TYPE1;       // TYPE1 = shared_ptr<int> 

TYPE1 value = new std::remove_pointer<TYPE1>::type()    // make a new  shared_ptr<int>
```

Any ideas how to achieve this with boost?

Answer (score 3):

The [`variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/variant.html) contains an [MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/index.html) [sequence](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/concepts.html) called `types`, which you can use to access the types.

```
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>

typedef typename boost::mpl::at_c<VType::types, 0>::type TYPE1;
```